# What's the numpy/pythonic way to non-destructively replace a column x of a matrix with f(x)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix `M`:

```
import numpy

M = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

I want a function that returns an array with every entry `x` of the `col`th column of `M` replaced by `f(x)`, but doesn't modify the input matrix.

I'm doing this with:

```
def my_func(M, col, f=lambda x: x+1):
    copy = numpy.copy(M)
    copy.T[col] = [f(x[col]) for x in copy]
    return copy
```

which works out well:

```
>>> my_func([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], 1)
array([[1, 3, 3],
       [4, 6, 6]])
```

But I'm seeing that this code is a huge bottleneck in my program, since my matrix M is large. Is there a faster way to do this?

I've also tried

```
numpy.fromiter(map(lambda x: f(x), M.T[col]), dtype=float)
```

but this doesn't seem to yield a whole lot of speed-up.

(In reality, my matrix `M` is actually a `numpy.masked_array`, and `f` is more complex than just adding 1, but I don't know if those details make any difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should help the siuation. Using `%timeit` in ipython, I got `100000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 us per loop` for your function and `100000 loops, best of 3: 9.83 us per loop` for the one listed below.

```
import numpy

M = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

def my_func(M, col, f=lambda x: x+1):
    copy = numpy.copy(M)
    copy[:, col] = f(copy[:, col])
    return copy

print my_func(M, 1)
```

The one issue with my version is that `f` has to work on vector input. However, using `vecor_func = numpy.vectorize(func)` this can be done for any function, but it might efect the time boost of my method.

Another cool thing is that this can be done for more complicated indexing/slices.

```
def my_func2(M, index, f=lambda x: x+1):
    copy = numpy.copy(M)
    copy[index] = f(copy[index])
    return copy

# prints the same result as before
print my_func2(M, (slice(None), 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you just apply your function to the whole column at once?

```
def my_func(M, col, f=lambda x: x+1):
    copy = numpy.copy(M)
    copy[:,col] = f(M[:,col])
    return copy
```

Doing a matrix-scale operation is going to be faster than iterating through element by element.